# How to remove log calls in J2SE/J2EE application (not Android)

Tags: java, logging, proguard

I know that removing logger calls with Proguard works for Android applications.

How can one accomplish this in standard Java application?

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Clazz {

      private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Clazz.class.getName());

      public void foo() {
          LOGGER.info("bar");
      }

}
```

in my Proguard configuration I have the following:

```
-assumenosideeffects class java.util.logging.Logger { *; }
-whyareyoukeeping class java.util.logging.Logger
```

which gives the following output when running:

```
 [proguard] java.util.logging.Logger
 [proguard]   is a library class.
```

I understand that it's a library but I want to strip all calls to it anyway. Is this possible with Proguard? If not, why? How come this works so conveniently for Android, does the logger field or lack of it have something to do with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to remove logging calls like this, assuming you haven't disabled optimization -- it's the optimization step that removes unnecessary and unwanted calls. ProGuard can't remove the Logger class itself, since it is a run-time library class, as you've seen.

You mustn't use a wildcard for matching the methods though, since this includes essential methods like wait() and finalize() (affecting all classes). You'll have to enumerate the methods that you want to remove. For instance:

```
-assumenosideeffects class java.util.logging.Logger {
    void info(java.lang.String);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What happened was that we were using a custom logging interface that was extending org.slf4j.Logger. The actual log calls were hitting on that interface and not the custom one specified in Proguard config. Lesson learned as a Proguard user: double check your class/interface method signatures!